# Excel - Conditional Format Row if one cell is blank and the other is populated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

So I'm trying to create a quick conditional format that will format an entire row orange if there isn't a value in col c and a value in col b. Below is what i've tried to tinker with.

```
and($b2="",$c2<>"")
```

Should also note I am applying this to a range of cells lets say $a$1:$d$6

Comment: If you are applying the CF to A1:D6 then the formula should be `=AND($B1="",$C1<>"")`,

Comment: Excel will only add quotes if you don't start the formula with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something in your apply to range that's not making it work. I built [this sample spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g6trDCgHkU6xpTO-uw?e=knycHz) which seems to work. See settings below.

[image: Formula Rule]

[image: Applies to Range]